# MySQL prefix SET field values with custom string

Tags: mysql, string

I have a MySQL 5 database table field `media` like `set('audio','video','photo')`
What i need to do, is in single SELECT statement prefix it's values with some custom string  and space after it, if any of the values are present. For example:

`audio,video` becomes `mediaaudio mediavideo`

`photo` becomes `mediaphoto`

The specifics of the data does not require an external relationship table to be made for corresponding values, so `set` is sufficient for the current task. I need to prefix them to uniquely identify them later in search results.

Real example:

`id   media`

`1    audio,video`

`2    audio`

`3    video`

`4    photo,video`

`5`

Expected result:

`id   media`

`1    mediaaudio mediavideo`

`2    mediaaudio`

`3    mediavideo`

`4    mediaphoto mediavideo`

`5`

Comment: I don't understand. Use `CONCAT`?

Comment: are the values separated by a comma or not? i think if you have an enum field, you can only have one value per column.

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake. It's sa SET column

Comment: Easy with `concat` / `concat` with a case statement I think... unless you are storing those comma separated values in a single field?

Comment: show us sample records (*maybe 3 or 4 records*) with your desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with `INSTR`, `CONCAT`, `REPLACE` and `LENGTH`:

```
SELECT ID, 
  CASE WHEN INSTR(YourField, ',') > 0
    THEN CONCAT('media', REPLACE(YourField, ',', ' media'))
    WHEN LENGTH(YourField) > 0
    THEN CONCAT('media', YourField) 
    ELSE ''
   END media
FROM YourTable
```

And the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/798e4/5).

Good luck.